# Emberjs Index vs Application

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I cannot grok or find proper documentation for elaborating on Emberjs' "application" and "index" view/controller/template. Are they interchangeable?

For example,

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('index', { path: '/' });
});
```

When I navigate to the root URL, it renders the "application" template and the context is "application" controller - meanwhile, I have specifically named the resource Index. My expectation is that it would then use the "IndexView" and "IndexController".

Can anyone clarify these things or point me in the direction of good documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss the concept of "outlet" to fully understand what is going on.

In your application, the resources are injected in the application template via an injection point called outlet.

Just add {{outlet}} in your application template.

See here for doc http://emberjs.com/guides/application/the-application-template/

Comment: I do understand this. Unfortunately that documentation does not begin to explain in enough detail for me to get an understanding. Am I to understand that my resouse 'index' would take a template called 'index' and render it in the {{outlet}} of the 'application' template? If so, which controller will be used? Will the IndexView be a child view of the Application View?

Comment: Yes you are right, and the IndexView inserted will be managed by the IndexController. As far as i know {{outlet}} is just a placeholder for injection, it does not define view inheritance.